# Generating packets

Tags: c, networking, protocols

I want to know how to generate a packet in c. Supposed we have a type as follows:

```
struct ipheader {
    int version;
    int hdLen;
    int tos;
    int totLen;
    int id;
    ......
    int dstIp;
}
```

And we have a ipheader type:

```
struct ipheader ip;

//init the ip
.....
```

How can I generate a packet(just ip header part) from "ip". Could anyone show me how?

I want to know to generate packets with information such as  mac address, ip header, tcp header, payload. Then I can use the "pcap_sendpacket" function to send the packets I have generated. Could someone give me a little example.

Comment: "Generate a packet?"  What does that even mean in this context?

Comment: you arent properly specifying the lengths of the fields ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom ip packet as below. The below code snippet also makes the custom TCP part which is inside the ip packet. Also the custom function checksum generates the checksum for the packet. You can use rawsocket to send this packet directly to the network. I think the code is easy and self explanatory. Let me know if you have any queries.

```
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>


****************************************
ipv4 packet structure
****************************************
struct ipv4_packet {
    struct iphdr iph;
    struct tcphdr tcph;
    void *data;
};


****************************************
snippet of the IPV4 packet making code
****************************************
struct iphdr ip_head;
struct tcphdr tcp_head;
struct sockaddr_in target;
char packet[2048];
int i;

struct tcp_pseudo /*the tcp pseudo header*/
{
    __u32 src_addr;
    __u32 dst_addr;
    __u8 dummy;
    __u8 proto;
    __u16 length;
} pseudohead;

struct help_checksum /*struct for checksum calculation*/
{
    struct tcp_pseudo pshd;
    struct tcphdr tcphd;
    char tcpdata[1024];
} tcp_chk_construct;

/*Prepare IP header*/
ip_head.ihl = 5; /*headerlength with no options*/
ip_head.version = 4;
ip_head.tos = 0;
ip_head.tot_len = htons(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + len);
ip_head.id = htons(31337 + (rand() % 100));
ip_head.frag_off = 0;
ip_head.ttl = 255;
ip_head.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
ip_head.check = 0; /*Fill in later*/
ip_head.saddr = htonl(src);
ip_head.daddr = htonl(dst);
ip_head.check = in_cksum((unsigned short *) &ip_head, sizeof(struct iphdr));

/*Prepare TCP header*/
tcp_head.source = htons(src_p);
tcp_head.dest = htons(dst_p);
tcp_head.seq = htonl(seq);
tcp_head.ack_seq = htonl(ack);
tcp_head.doff = 5;

/* set or reset ack, fin or syn flags as needed */
tcp_head.ack = 0;
tcp_head.syn = 0;
tcp_head.fin = 0;

tcp_head.res1 = 0;
tcp_head.urg = 0;
tcp_head.psh = 0;
tcp_head.rst = 0;
tcp_head.res2 = 0;

tcp_head.window = htons(0x7c00);
tcp_head.check = 0; /*Fill in later*/
tcp_head.urg_ptr = 0;

/*Assemble structure for checksum calculation and calculate checksum*/
pseudohead.src_addr = ip_head.saddr;
pseudohead.dst_addr = ip_head.daddr;
pseudohead.dummy = 0;
pseudohead.proto = ip_head.protocol;
pseudohead.length = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr) + len);

tcp_chk_construct.pshd = pseudohead;
tcp_chk_construct.tcphd = tcp_head;
memcpy(tcp_chk_construct.tcpdata, buffer, len);

tcp_head.check = in_cksum((unsigned short *) &tcp_chk_construct,
        sizeof(struct tcp_pseudo) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + len);

/*Assemble packet*/
memcpy(packet, (char *) &ip_head, sizeof(ip_head));
memcpy(packet + sizeof(ip_head), (char *) &tcp_head, sizeof(tcp_head));
memcpy(packet + sizeof(ip_head) + sizeof(tcp_head), buffer, len);

/*Send packet*/
target.sin_family = AF_INET;
target.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_head.daddr;
target.sin_port = tcp_head.dest;
i = sendto(sfd, packet, sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + len,
        0, (struct sockaddr *) &target, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (i < 0)
    return (-1); /*Error*/
else
    return (i); /*Return number of bytes sent*/


****************************************        
FUNCTION FOR CHECKSUM   
****************************************
/* function to calculate the checksum for the packet */
unsigned short in_cksum(unsigned short *ptr, int nbytes) {

    register long sum; /* assumes long == 32 bits */
    u_short oddbyte;
    register u_short answer; /* assumes u_short == 16 bits */
    /*
     * the algorithm is simple, using a 32-bit accumulator (sum),
     * we add sequential 16-bit words to it, and at the end, fold back
     * all the carry bits from the top 16 bits into the lower 16 bits.
     */
    sum = 0;
    while (nbytes > 1) {
        sum += *ptr++;
        nbytes -= 2;
    }

    /* mop up an odd byte, if necessary */
    if (nbytes == 1) {
        oddbyte = 0; /* make sure top half is zero */
        *((u_char *) &oddbyte) = *(u_char *) ptr; /* one byte only */
        sum += oddbyte;
    }

    /*
     * Add back carry outs from top 16 bits to low 16 bits.
     */
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff); /* add high-16 to low-16 */
    sum += (sum >> 16); /* add carry */
    answer = ~sum; /* ones-complement, then truncate to 16 bits */
    return (answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the details (looks suspiciously like homework to me as well), all i can do is give pointers.

1. Look up how structures are formed in the memory.
2. Look up Ip header format which will show you what member is where in an Ip header.
3. Look up Raw sockets.

So, provided you properly structure your struct and use raw sockets, you only need to write this struct to the socket.