# populating headers fields in skb

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to make a kernel module in which I would be able to send the packet from my kernel module. the thing is how should I populate the network_header, transport header and mac header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not so much concerned with the mac header, then have a look at this code to generate the packets 
[Generating packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990857/generating-packets)